# SIM868 GNSS Not outputting the data from AT+CGNSINF command

Tags: gps, gsm, at-command, sim-card, nmea

I've been developing a PCB board with the SIM868. And per the 'SIM868_Series_Hardware_Design_V1.06' I implemented the "All-in-one Mode"
[image: All in one Mode]

My Schematic is as follow:

[image: SCH Snap]

I've been following the GNSS sequence per the 'SIM868_GNSS_Application Note_V1.00' document.

It basically instructs you to follow the AT commands

1. Turn on GNSS module [`AT+CGNSPWR=1`]
2. Set NMEA sentence [`AT+CGNSSEQ="RMC"`]
3. Query GNSS info [`AT+CGNSINF`]

The problem I'm having is that when I request the GNSS info, i get the following output

```
**+CGNSINF: 0,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,** .
```

The first parameter (Which is GNSS run status] is set always to '0' when it should be '1' since I send the [AT+CGNSPWR=1] first and the module reply correctly [OK reply]. Also the 10k [R49] pull-up is installed between GNSS_EN and GPIO1.

If I look at the trace of GPS_TX [pin 61], I do get the NMEA sentences and the LAT,LON,VEL,UTC etc parameters.

I have measured the UART2_RXD [pin23] and it effectively gets the UART signal from the GNSS module

The FW version of the SIM868 is [1418B02SIM868M32].

Any guess why it fails to request the GNSS info?

Comment: maybe a power supply unit issue: possible solution here https://arduino.stackexchange.com/a/54478/48096

Comment: Hi Victor Vargas.
I have exactly the same problem.
Did you find the reason?

Comment: It was soldering issues, between the GPS uart and the uart2. Since I was had soldering them that was the cause but a reflow did it

Answer (score 0):

I have similar pcb design. Had a GNSS problems too. Finally it's working. Have 1 exception in design. I'm not using R49(R101). GNSS_EN is controlled with MCU. Problems was in soldering quality. After resolving this problems - my output is +CGNSINF: 1,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,, and have a fix in short time.